# Fedora how to automatically run the ssh daemon - install from source

Tags: fedora

I would like to know what are the ways to automatically start daemons (sshd) in Fedora system. I know I can write a startup script that will put on `/etc/init.d/`.

What are the other options?

Somewhere I read that now in the new version of this can be done using the commands in the terminal, but I do not remember what it was.

My 2 question. I install ssh from source. When keys are generated for a server? During the installation?

Comment: `chkconfig` perhaps? Also, I assume you mean sshd, not ssh? ssh-keygen to generate your own keys (not server keys)

Comment: I also read about `systemctl`. Yes, I mean sshd. I mean if the server - daemon to work properly are automatically generated keys? The lecturer has mentioned.

Comment: Yes, installing sshd *should* install the public and private server keys. On my machine, it's `systemsettings` on the off chance that helps anyone

Comment: Do *not* write a shell script and put it in `/etc/init.d/`. Also, you don't need chkconfig. Those things are used on SysV init based systems. However, Fedora (like many other popular distributions nowadays) is based on sytemd. systemd does not need a shell script for every service, instead it uses service unit files. Those contain the same information regarding what is started and how but without the shell code around it (which was usually mostly identical in most scripts anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fedora 20, there's a directory

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
```

I didn't compile from source.  Unless I'm mistaken these are the files/links which enable the commands below.

The file is a link to

```
sshd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
```

Here's an example of the default sshd file.

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
After=syslog.target network.target auditd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-keygen
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you have the symbolic link in the location above, pointing to a file that contains the configuration above you'll be able to use the systemctl commands below.

Assuming you're using a version of Fedora 15 or later...

```
systemctl start sshd
systemctl enable sshd
```

The first command will start, the second command will enable auto-starting at boot.

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Will restart the service.

Also see

```
systemctl status sshd
```

The same series of systemctl commands work for various services.  To see a list of running services...

```
systemctl list-units --type service
```